# How to pass Object to mutation of apollo graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I try to pass variables to my mutation in react project. It is **working** static code:

```
const EDIT_WORD = gql`
  mutation {
    editWord(
      eng_word: "apple"
      data: { eng_word: "apple1", ru_word: "яблоко1" }
    ) {
      eng_word
    }
  }
...
const [editWordHook] = useMutation(EDIT_WORD);
...
editWordHook();
```

It is code with some mistake:

```
const EDIT_WORD = gql`
  mutation($eng_word: String!, $data: wordInput!) {
    editWord(
      eng_word: $eng_word
      data: { eng_word: $eng_word, ru_word: $ru_word }
    ) {
      eng_word
    }
  }
  `;
...
const [editWordHook] = useMutation(EDIT_WORD);
...
editWordHook({
        variables: {
          eng_word: editedWord,
          data: {
            eng_word: englishWordText,
            ru_word: russianWordText,
          },
        },
      });
```

Instead of [$data: wordInput!] I tried

```
$data: { $eng_word: String!, $ru_word: String! }
```

But is didn't help...  Error log didn't provide anything valuable:

```
// value or the constructed error will be meaningless.
> 46 | constructor({
     | ^  47 |   graphQLErrors,
  48 |   networkError,
  49 |   errorMessage,
```

Already spent 10 hours and can't find mistake...

Comment: sometimes this happens, can you paste the query on playground and try to paste it back into the code section after making sure that it works there? Do you also use prettier?

Comment: Yes, I passed this query in playground and it works there...  I used prettier, but probably I don't have extension for gql

Comment: Actually, you can try to install, sometimes it happened in me. If it wasn't pretty, I understood that there was a problem. Sometimes it can be caused by empty spacers.

Comment: you passed right variables (`eng_word`, `data` - required with API, explorable by graphiql docs) but used bad query, it was enough to `editWord(
      eng_word: $eng_word
      data: $data
    )` ..... **just learn to use 'query variables' in graphiql before coding**

Answer (score 2):

You pass variables

```
      { eng_word: editedWord,
              data: {
                eng_word: englishWordText,
                ru_word: russianWordText,
              }
       }
```

to your `editWordHook` function, but your `EDIT_WORD` mutation does not expect it.

```
const EDIT_WORD = gql`
  mutation($eng_word: String!, $data: wordInput!) {
    editWord(
      eng_word: $eng_word
      data: { eng_word: $eng_word, ru_word: $ru_word }
    ) {
      eng_word
    }
  }
  `;
```

Your `EDIT_WORD` mutation does not have required params

```
const EDIT_WORD = gql`
  mutation($eng_word: String!, $data: wordInput!) {
    editWord(
      eng_word: $eng_word
      data: { eng_word: $eng_word, ru_word: $ru_word }
    ) {
      eng_word
    }
  }
  `;
```

As you can see mutations input params are `$eng_word: String!` and `$data: wordInput!` but you use `$ru_word` there.

If you `data` variable is corresponds to `wordInput!` type, try to use whole data object to the mutation

```
const EDIT_WORD = gql`
  mutation($eng_word: String!, $data: wordInput!) {
    editWord(
      eng_word: $eng_word
      data: $data
    ) {
      eng_word
    }
  }
  `;
```

Comment: I tried const EDIT_WORD = gql`
    mutation($eng_word: String!, $data: {  $eng_word: String!, $ru_word: String! } ) {
      editWord(
        eng_word: $eng_word
        data: { eng_word: $eng_word, ru_word: $ru_word }
      ) {
        eng_word
      }
    }
  `;   But is does not work as well

Comment: Or also tried     const EDIT_WORD = gql`
    mutation($eng_word: String!, $ru_word: String!) {
      editWord(
        eng_word: $eng_word
        data: { eng_word: $eng_word, ru_word: $ru_word }
      ) {
        eng_word
      }
    }
  `;   Doesn't work...

Comment: You both forgot a comma, right after `$eng_word`, @NikitaPolevoy I think your second attempt in the 
 comments should work if you puth `$eng_word, data`

Comment: I tried with millions options but not...  I gave up and changed schema :-(

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everybody who tried to help me! I gave up and changed my schema to uglier version...

```
editWord(
    edited_eng_word: String!
    new_eng_word: String!
    new_ru_word: String!
  ): Word!
```

Now it does't require object and works. 
...I hate graphQl

Comment: I am glad that you had a work around, but in my case and case of other they still need to deal with an object as the server is already defined

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem as you.
I found the solution in my side.

```
const EDIT_WORD = gql`
  mutation($eng_word: String!, $data: wordInput!) {
    editWord(
      eng_word: $eng_word,
      data: $data
    ) {
      eng_word
    }
  }
`;
```

You may have to do like this.
and when call this mutation, do like this:

```
editWord({
    variables: {
        eng_word: 'XXX'
        data: {
            eng_word: "YYY",
            ru_word: "ZZZ",
        }
    }
}).then(
).catch(
)
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a mutation request when you want to pass an object as a varible

```
const CREATE_GAME = gql`
      mutation createGame($game: CreateGameInput!) {
        createGame(input: $game) {
          name
        }
      }
    `;


const [createGameDB] = useMutation(CREATE_GAME);
await createGameDB({ variables: {game: preparedGameToDb}})
```

CreateGameInput it's the input that you defined on your server. In my case it looks like that

```
@InputType()
export class CreateGameInput {    
        @Field(() => String)
        name: String;
        @Field(type => [TeamInput], { nullable: true })
        teams: TeamInput[];
        @Field(type => [MemberInput], { nullable: true })
        members: MemberInput[]
        @Field(type => [GameWordInput], { nullable: true })
        words: GameWordInput[];
}
```

Comment: Q about apollo-client, not server ... API already uses (object accepting) input type - `wordInput`